# ASP.net Check if User is logged in Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have been playing with JQuery ajax and an ASP.Net webservice.  I would like to use this combination to do more than look up information.  I would like to add lines to orders and and do other things that will open up holes for security if there is no way to check if the user is logged in or not.
Javascript user checking before running the ajax will not shield from attacks by a semi aware hacker.  Am I bound to use ASP.net controls to do all significant data entry?

Comment: Well, in asp.net using postbacks are best way to transfer data to the server, but if you have to use ajax, you can specify `type='post'` for your ajax call. This eliminates the visiblity of transferred data and hence safer.

Comment: @user1 couldn't the user look at the javacript and figure out what to do?

Comment: @HelloW That's why you have to validate on the server that the current user has permission to do what they are trying to do. But you should be doing that with non-ajax requests as well.

Comment: Yes, there is always a risk when processing sensitive data at front end. Don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but safe way is to use postbacks. By the way, why not check if the user is logged in or not on pageload and render the controls according to it.

Comment: I am not trying to process from the front end and your comments are well taken.  I am checking to make sure the user is logged in before rendering the controls.  
I am now checking to make sure the user is logged in before doing anything server side.
I didn't know if the cookies came along with an ajax call from jquery.  Yes I am a noob :)  thanks to all for the prompt help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax requests send all the same headers (including authentication cookies) as normal requests. Just validate the user against the attempted action and specific data, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to verify (on the server side) that the current user is logged in.  This is easy with MVC by just putting an [[Authorize] attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) on the Controller or Method.